# Activate another viewcontroller in splitviewcontroller

Tags: c#, xamarin.mac

Im develop desktop app using xamarin.mac . i have followed xamarin.mac sample project that use splitview. Now, i want to navigate from this viewcontroller where user need to choose between 2 radio button.

[image]

If user choose USB Token and click continue button, it will navigate to this(which replace the current viewcontroller)

[image]

Right now, i dont have any idea how to do it. Please help me with this. For sample project please click this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/samples/xamarin/mac-samples/maccontrols/)

**UPDATE**

I already instantiate RightViewController and performSegue but none of this worked.

```
//Button Actions **Continue**
partial void SelectStorage(NSObject sender)
    {
        RightViewController rightView = new RightViewController();

        if (SelectedStorage == "Token")
        {
            PerformSegue("LoginSegue", rightView); // 1st try

            PerformSegue("LoginSegue", this);    //2nd try

            rightView.ShowView(SubviewType.Login);  //3rd try
        }
        else
        {
            PerformSegue("SoftCertSegue", this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you take the example code from the link. Add a viewcontroller to the story board. Create a segue with an identifer (ctrl-click from 'Right View Controller' and drag to the new viewcontroller). Look at the other segues and how they work.

Comment: Look at RightViewController.cs to see how to initiate the segue with 'PerformSegue'

Comment: @svn okay, already follow your step in xcode, my update code above did not work

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of 'Navigation' in the macOS app, at least not inside of the window. You can instantiate new `ViewControler` and replace the `View` that you want to replace.

Comment: I've instantiate the RightViewController but any of my line of code worked, see my edited post

Comment: @dejulzZul I’ve suggested that you set the view explicitly not to perform segue.